# Configure app package name

Tags: deployment, uwp

I have a UWP app that's associated with an app in the Microsoft Store. We intend to distribute this app via the Microsoft Store and manually (via the side-loading feature).

When I create the app package (*Store->Create App Packages*), the file/folder names appear to be based on the Project file name.

Is there any way I can configure the file name for the app package? I want to keep my project file name, but I don't want it to be used for the package file/folder names.

Alternatively, can I just rename the files manually (it looks like the `Add-AppDebPackage.ps1` script is written in a generic way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing on my side, if rename the `appx` or bundle files in the app package folder, it seems like there is no influence on installing the app. You still can install the app by double click the renamed bundle file or run the `Add-AppDebPackage.ps1`.  As you guessed, the file names are not hard code in `Add-AppDebPackage.ps1`. But the folder and suffix of files should not be changed.

For your scenario you could try to [manual package the app](http://tps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/manual-packaging-root) instead of packing the app by Visual Studio automatically. When creating the package with `MakeAppx.exe` tool manually you could assign the name of the package created with the `<output package name>` argument, this is the file name appended with `.appx`. As the same, when creating the bundle file there is  `<output bundle name>` argument. Details please reference [Create an app package with the MakeAppx.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool).